# Tools available to catch exceptions within a .NET application

Tags: .net, debugging, exception

I'm looking for a tool (free or commercial) that can attach to a .NET 4+ process and catch exceptions thrown within the process. Once caught, the tool should be able to provide a stack trace and perhaps other debugging information.

We had a (internal) tool that could do this but it does not work now that some of our applications have been upgraded. A update to the tool I mentioned is not possible.

I've Google'd this topic several times in the past and never found anything relevant or useful so now I'm finally reaching out for assistance.

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the library/tool I am looking for is Mdbg from Microsoft.

NuGet has a package for Mdbg that is compatible for .NET 4+.

You can also download the source code for Mdbg for .NET 2 and .NET 4 if that is more helpful.

[MdbgEngine from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.MdbgEngine/)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio can do this. Select *Attach to Process* and enable *Break on Exceptions*.

The free 'express' version will probably do this as well.